# SQLite3 statement SELECT, WHERE and ORDER BY on Obj-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, sqlite

I have a problem with SQLite3 on Xcode.
the problem is that I have this database:

```
-------------------------|
| ID | Company  |  Model |
|------------------------|
| 1  | Audi     |  A4    |
| 2  | Audi     |  A4    |
| 3  | Audi     |  A3    |
| 4  | Audi     |  A4    |
| 5  | BMW      |  330Ci |
| 6  | BMW      |  330Ci |
| 7  | BMW      |  750i  |
| 8  | Mercedes |  CL65  |
| 9  | Mercedes |  CL65  |
--------------------------
```

I want the sqlite3 to show me like this:

```
-------------------------|
| ID | Company  |  Model |
|------------------------|
| 1  | Audi     |  A4    |
| 2  | Audi     |  A3    |
| 3  | BMW      |  330Ci |
| 4  | BMW      |  750i  |
| 5  | Mercedes |  CL65  |
--------------------------
```

I have this function:

```
-(NSString *)loadModel
{
    thecars = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"The data has been loaded to the pickers."];
    sqlite3_stmt * sqlStatement;
    @try {
        NSString *dbPath = [self path];
        if(sqlite3_open([[self path]UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"**** Database found at path.");
        }
        if(!(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK))
        {
            NSLog(@"**** An error has occured: %@", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        }
        NSString * hello = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT DISTINCT Model FROM Comp WHERE Company=%@",theChoosenCompany];
        const char * sql = [hello UTF8String];
        if(sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"**** Problem with prepare statement: %@", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        }
        else
        {
            while (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                NSString * model = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 2)]; // Car models
                [modelsArray addObject:model];
            }
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"**** Problem with prepare statement:  %@", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }
    @finally {
        sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatement);
        sqlite3_close(db);
        return thecars;
    }
}
```

the problem is that I always gets an error and the program crush with error "Thread 1: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"".

I believe that the stament is wrong.

Please if someone can help, i'm new to objective-c so please be patient.

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd start stepping through the code line-by-line in a debugger and see precisely what line is causing the problem.

As an aside, I don't see where you're setting theChoosenCompany. Is that properly quoted and stuff like that?

Also, if you want unique combinations of Model & Company, isn't it just

```
SELECT Model, Company FROM Comp GROUP BY Model, Company
```

Obviously I don't know your logic, as you said above you wanted just the unique Model/Company combinations, but your code seems to try to retrieve unique models for a given company.

Finally, there are Objective C wrappers for SQLite3, such as FMDB (at https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb), that get you out of the weeds of sqlite3 calls for stuff like this.

Comment: Robert, thanks for your comment. theChoosenCompany is equal to the company that is clicked on the view before. I just want to get all the models of the spesific company, but each model, just one time. is 'SELECT Model, Company FROM Comp GROUP BY Mode, Company' will do the trick?

Comment: for example, I used 'SELECT Model FROM Comp WHERE Company = Audi'. but I just want each Model to be showed once. how to do it?

Comment: The standard SQL for that is `SELECT Model FROM Comp WHERE Company = 'Audi' GROUP BY Model`. The `GROUP BY` is what gives you the unique responses. You could also do things like `SELECT Model, COUNT(*) FROM Comp WHERE Company = 'Audi' GROUP BY Model` which would give you the models and how many occurrences of each it found. By the way, note the single quotes around 'Audi', which designates it as a literal string, rather than a column name.

Comment: By the way, I don't know if you're already doing this, but as you're learning about SQL, sometimes it's nice to have an interface for opening your database and just trying out SQL statements. You can type "sqlite3" followed by the name of your database if you want a command line interface. Or you can use GUI tools like Base available at http://menial.co.uk/. It's easier to test and master your SQL in a tool like one of these, and only then incorporate it into your program once you're comfortable with your SQL. Helps separate Objective C issues from SQL ones.

Comment: Thanks alot man, the SELECT Model FROM Comp WHERE Company = 'Audi' GROUP BY 'bla bla' worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly green on SQLite myself, but if you select only the models, wouldn't it be column 0 and not column 2 in this line:  `NSString * model = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 2)]; // Car models` ?